# Default C++ nature of Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I know that VS2008 supports all, general C++, Managed C++ & C++/CLI.

What will be the default nature of VS2008? If I don't say anything then which C++ (C++, Managed C++ & C++/CLI.) will it use? Is it general C++? or Managed or CLI version?

I just want to do regular C++ programming. Not managed or CLI. So, I want to change settings appropriately. I don't want to change these settings for every project I create. How can I do that?

Just in case, if I need in future how do I tell it to use Managed C++ & C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the project you pick.  If you just pick a plane ol' C++ console or Windows app, that's what you'll get.

If you decide you want to write managed C++ later, you just have to go into the project and change the appropriate settings, and of course write managed C++ code—it doesn't convert for free.  Not sure about CLI.

Comment: For Managed C++ and C++/CLI, on the project's property sheets ("General" page), you can select either `/clr:oldSyntax` (for Managed C++) or `/clr` (for C++/CLI).  `/clr:oldSyntax` is deprecated.